# Can a class written to work with a function object also work with a lambda or std::function type?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, functor, std-function

I've written a template class to work with a no-argument void-returning function object:

```
//...Class declaration here...

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::Alarm(const FunctionObject& fn)
    : StopWatch(), _delegate(fn), _tickTime(1.0), _run_count(-1) { /* DO NOTHING */ }

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::Alarm(double tickTime, const FunctionObject& fn)
    : StopWatch(), _delegate(fn), _tickTime(tickTime), _run_count(-1) { /* DO NOTHING */ }

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::Alarm(double tickTime, int run_count, const FunctionObject& fn)
    : StopWatch(), _delegate(fn), _tickTime(tickTime), _run_count(run_count < -1 ? -1 : run_count) { /* DO NOTHING */ }

template<class FunctionObject>
Alarm<FunctionObject>::~Alarm() {
    if(_isRunning) Stop();
}

template<class FunctionObject>
FunctionObject Alarm<FunctionObject>::Tick() {
    if(IsRunning() == false) return _delegate;

    if(GetElapsedTimeInSeconds() >= _tickTime) {
        Reset();
        if(_run_count == 0) return _delegate;
        _delegate();
        if(_run_count > -1) --_run_count;
        Start();
    }
    return _delegate;
}
```

Will this work if the user attempts to pass in a lambda or `std::function`?

If not, it doesn't seem simply adding a constructor that takes a lambda (is that even possible?) or `std::function` will work either.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using trailing default parameters?

Comment: `std::function` and lambdas _are_ functors / function objects. They're nothing special (lambdas are shorthands, nothing more).

Comment: Note that the standard library precedent is to pass "callables" by value rather than const reference. Also note that while your use appears to be fine here there are *many* cases where leading `_` are forbidden and a simple rule is to just avoid such leading `_` entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a template that's parameterised on the function object's class, yes, it should work with all callable objects.

Comment: I suspect with non-void returning objects, the return type will just be ignored, but will there be an error if the lambda/std::function passed in has arguments?

Comment: @Casey: Why would it "be ignored"? The return type is part of a function type. I'm failing to see what the problem is here. Of course that may just be because we have no idea what `_delegate` is. Why don't you just _try it and see_??